# Create XML element with attributes C# has extra xmls=""

Tags: c#, xml

Following is my requirement. I am reading an xml file (*.csproj file) and searching for a node in it. After I find the node I will insert my element into it.
Following is my original XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="Stdafx.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="NewFile.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Following is my code snippet to do this.

```
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load(inputFile);

        XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);
        string strNamespace = xDoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI;
        nsMgr.AddNamespace("ns", strNamespace);
        XmlNode root = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/ns:Project/ns:ItemGroup/ns:ClInclude", nsMgr);

        XmlAttribute attr = xDoc.CreateAttribute("Include");
        attr.Value = "NewHeaderFile.h";

        XmlElement xele = xDoc.CreateElement("ClInclude");
        xele.Attributes.Append(attr);

        root.ParentNode.AppendChild(xele);
        xDoc.Save(outFile);
```

This is the output what i get.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="Stdafx.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="NewFile.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="NewHeaderFile.h" xmlns="" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Problem Statement:
I want to ignore the **xmlns=""** in my output.
My output should look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="Stdafx.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="NewFile.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="NewHeaderFile.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Kinldy help me.
Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your element declaration with following and should work

```
XmlElement xele = xDoc.CreateElement("ClInclude", xDoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
```

Add the namespace on root mean that your element are in the `'root' namespace`, so there is no need to add a `'no namespace'` to new element

Comment: Thanks for the help @InvernoMuto. After changing the element declaration it worked as I expected.

Answer (score 3):

All elements in the original document are in namespace  `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"`, whereas you are creating the new `ClInclude` element in the empty namespace `""`. If you also create this element in `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"`, the extraneous `xmlns=""` will be omitted from the output xml.

Comment: Thanks for the help @StuartLC. It worked as you have stated. I created the element with the original namespace.